# Query was empty error while selecting and updating the record?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, railo

I am wondering why I am getting this error `"Query is Empty"` as I checked the queries which are working fine in Sqlyog. Can anyone please help me out by explaning what's wrong in this query ? Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code. I am using Railo 4.2.0 on Ubuntu.

```
<cfquery name="q" datasource="#getDSN()#">
    SELECT is_nav_item, nav_order, MAX(nav_order) AS maxNavOrder 
    FROM content
    WHERE id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.id#">
    OR site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="#getDSN()#">
    <!--- 
       check to see if existing record has 0 and in arguments it is 
       passed as 1 then we are going to update the nav order by selecting 
       max nav order in the table then incrementing the maxNavOrder by 1
    --->
    <cfif q.is_nav_item EQ 0 AND arguments.is_nav_item EQ 1>
        UPDATE content
        SET nav_order = #q.maxNavOrder+1#
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
        AND site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
    </cfif>

    <!--- 
        check to see if the existing record have is_nav_item eq 1 and in 
        the arguments it is 0 if it is then its going to update the nav_order 
        to 0... so that we can prevent it being updating the nav order in case 
        someone not updating nav_item but something else
    --->
    <cfif q.is_nav_item EQ 1 AND arguments.is_nav_item EQ 0>
        UPDATE content
        SET nav_order = 0
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
        AND site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
        ;
    </cfif>
 </cfquery>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have if statements inside your query... and if those both do not evaluate as true, your query could be an empty query.

Why not do an IF and put the whole query inside the IF statement... that way there is no way of getting an CFQUERY without any text in it.

```
<!--- 
  check to see if existing record has 0 and in arguments it is passed as 1 
  then we are going to update the nav order by selecting max nav order in 
  the table then incrementing the maxNavOrder by 1
--->
<cfif q.is_nav_item EQ 0 AND arguments.is_nav_item EQ 1>
     <cfquery datasource="#getDSN()#">
        UPDATE content
        SET    nav_order = #q.maxNavOrder+1#
        WHERE  id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
        AND site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
     </cfquery>
</cfif>

<!--- 
    check to see if the existing record have is_nav_item eq 1 and in the 
    arguments  it is 0.  if it is then its going to update the nav_order 
    to 0... so that we can prevent it being updating the nav order in case 
    someone not updating nav_item but something else
--->
<cfif q.is_nav_item EQ 1 AND arguments.is_nav_item EQ 0>
    <cfquery datasource="#getDSN()#">
       UPDATE content
       SET    nav_order = 0
       WHERE  id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
       AND    site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Comment: actually i heard that using cfquery number of times leads to performance issues because whenever cfquery tag executes it calls the database.

Comment: if do like this the first update is not working the second one is working.

Comment: If you use 1000s of queries, yes, you would want to group them somehow, but for basics, its perfectly fine to break them up like this. It makes it easier to read too.

If the second one runs, its overriding your first one... so both could run, but the are opposing each other.

Comment: Oh ok, I am wondering why my first update query is not working :(

Comment: If your arguments are right, they should run... by the looks of it. 
Are your tests passing in the right values, to the right records, that is what I would check.

If you were getting empty query before, there must be something not allowing that first IF statement to evaluate true... so check your inputs.

Comment: Are you supposed to be updating the record to set is_nav_item = 1 or to 0 in those queries too. You are not changing it at all in this code. That might be the issue here.

Comment: if that the case so it mustn't execute the second update query as well.

Comment: Not sure I follow you.
My question is, what is saving the is_nav_item into the database?
If it is supposed to be in this code, its missing. 

If its somewhere else, it might be affecting this. Updating before it checks the previous status.

Comment: is_nav_item is just a boolean value 0 or 1, before updating this I am checking in is it already 0 or 1 if it is 0 in db and in form it is 1 I am going to increment it with max nav order number similarly if it is 1 in db and in form it is 1 i am setting nav order to 0 that's it. why I did like this because if someone haven't update the is_nav_item they just updates something that time this queries must not be used.

Comment: (Edit) @GavinPickin - FYI, you can use the code button ie `{}` (or indent 4+ spaces) to post cfml.

Comment: Thanks Leigh, new to this... but just trying to help out where I can.